# Pass a variable from table to parent report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have one child table inside report.. Inside that table I have a variable that I want to use in parent report. Is it possible to pass it from table up to parent report?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the final value of a table subdataset variable back to the main report.  The value is returned at the end of each table instantiation.

The report JRXML would look something like the following.  You can use a different calculation type if you want to sum/aggregate the returned value in the main report.

```
<subDataset name="TableDataset">
  <variable name="SubdatasetVariable" class="java.lang.Integer" ../>
</subDataset>
<variable name="AVariable" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="System"/>
<jr:table >
  <datasetRun subDataset="TableDataset">
    <returnValue fromVariable="SubdatasetVariable" toVariable="AVariable" calculation="Nothing"/>
..
```